# Add TCP Option to ACK packet during 3-way handshake

Tags: c, tcp, linux-kernel, netfilter

I'm writing kernel module using netfilter. I just want to handle ACK for SYN/ACK (TCP three-way handshake). I use `skb_is_tcp_pure_ack` function, but ACK for data is also processed.

How can I do? My kernel version is **3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64**.

Current code looks like this:

```
struct iphdr *iph;
struct tcphdr *tcph;
struct net *net;

unsigned int hdr_len;
unsigned int tcphoff;

if (!skb_is_tcp_pure_ack(skb)) {
    return NF_ACCEPT;
}
/* add tcp option */

/* A netfilter instance to use */
static struct nf_hook_ops nfho __read_mostly = {
    .hook            = ato_hookfn,
    .pf              = PF_INET,
    .hooknum         = NF_INET_POST_ROUTING,
    .priority        = NF_IP_PRI_LAST,
    .owner           = THIS_MODULE,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

From the TCP state machine, you want to only match `ACK` packets when the state is `TCP_SYN_SENT`. Try adding another condition to check that, something like:

```
if (skb_is_tcp_pure_ack(skb) 
      && skb->sk->sk_state == TCP_SYN_SENT) {
  /*
   * ACK(-only) packet during three-way handshake
   */
}
```

Also, note that `skb_is_tcp_pure_ack` was introduced in kernel version **4.*** and not below.

Comment: thank you very much.TCP stack set state to TCP_ESTABLISHED when receive SYN/ACK by function tcp_rcv_synsent_state_process

Comment: It's not work.because the TCP state machine has been set TCP_ESTABLISHED when sending ACK for SYN/ACK

Comment: Indeed, looking at the code shows that `tcp_finish_connect` (where `TCP_ESTABLISHED` is set) is called right before `tcp_send_ack`. So my guess here is that you need to add a flag to tell if this is the first ACK encountered, for instance. Or maybe there is something you can use in tcp structure(s) that would tell you if this is before any data transmitted or something like that. What exactly is your use case? What do you want to achieve? Maybe there's another approach...

Comment: I' use toa [link](https://github.com/huaweicloud/elb-toa) to get real ip. so i need add TCP option at ACK packets

Comment: Well, I'm afraid you'll need to patch the kernel to achieve that, as it does not provide a hook for that precise step. So, as I said, maybe you can find a field in TCP structure(s) that would fit to check if this is the first ACK, otherwise, just add a flag